In Vite, is there a way to fallback for not-found files in the `publicDir`?
I have a Vue3 + Vite app, with images in my public folder. The structure is something like
root/
  public/
    {guid}.png
    {other_guid}.png
    ...
  src/
    components/
    main.ts

In the component that displays these images, I do
<img :src="'/' + item.guid + '.png'" />
This works well, but some of the items have a guid for which I don't have an image in public/ yet. I'd like to either:

Configure Vite to return a default .png file when it serves a request for one that is not found.
Somehow check if the image exists, and fallback to a known good URL if it doesn't. I'm guessing I could do a HEAD request with fetch(), but wondering if there's a vite-native way that perhaps doesn't involve an HTTP call.

What's the "accepted" way to achieve this in Vite/Vue3?

What do you mean "in Vite"? What's actually serving this - are you talking about the dev server (maybe you want to configure it), or something else?

I'm using the vite dev server in my dev environment, but I'm not sure where this'll be deployed so I guess I'm looking for solutions that aren't server-specific if they exist. I had hope that this was possible since Vite handles some of the URL resolution at least (the same path works in both dev mode and static build mode) but maybe it's not?

does this answer your question

@yoduh it does, thanks! Should've thought about looking for native solutions in the first place...
